# R No Workspace but Allocating 2+GB of Memory?

Tags: r, memory-management

I have been using R for a while, but this is the first time I have been trying to use it to play with "Big Data."  In addition, I am new to Ubuntu.

Currently, there is nothing in my workspace (I am using R Studio), but when I look at the System, the only open R session, generated by R Studio, is allocating over 2 GB of memory on my machine. See the screenshot below.

What am I missing?  I typically use rm(), but obviously that is not freeing up the memory.  Any help very much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: I would also suggest looking at the `data.table` package, if you haven't already. It plays nicely with large data because it avoids coping most of the time.

Answer (score 8):

I assume you allocated large objects before calling `rm`. Don't forget to remove any hidden objects (with names that start with ".").

You then need to call `gc` to actually collect and dispose of all the garbage...

```
# Remove all objects in the workspace
rm(list=ls(all=TRUE))

# Then collect garbage...
gc()
```